# What are the advantages of extending Python with C or C++?

Tags: c++, python, c

Recently I've read that we can code C/C++ and from python call those modules, I know that C/C++ is fast and strongly typed and those things but what advantages I got if I code some module and then call it from python? in what case/scenario/context it would be nice to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whomever put this on hold as opinion-based, I'm not so sure that this question qualifies.  If you look at the answers, they are all the same... speed and access to C libraries.  Those are definite answers, not opinions.

Comment: I just want to if is be able to delegate some heavy logic to c/c++ to gain speed on my app?

Answer (score 2):

Performance. That's why [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) is so fast (["The NumPy array: a structure for eﬃcient
numerical computation"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1523.pdf))

Comment: Or accessing system facilities or libraries which aren't exposed in python.

Comment: Yes, an example here can be `pcap` library and `pcapy` python wrapper

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need to access a system library that doesn't have a wrapper
   in python (Example: [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) wraps around libgeos to do
   geometrical computations), or if you're writing a wrapper around a
   system library.
2. If you have a performance bottleneck in a function
   that needs to be made a lot faster (and can benefit from using C).
   Like Charlie said, profiling is essential to find out whether you
   want to do this or not.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your application. If it really is spending time in a couple of places that you can recode in C consider doing so. Don't do this unless profiling tells you you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is there might be a C/C++ library with functionality not available in python.  You might write a python extension in C/C++ so that you can access/use that C/C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

The primary advantage I see is speed.  That's the price paid for the generality and flexibility of a dynamic language like Python.  The execution model of the language doesn't match the execution model of the processor, by a wide margin, so there must be a translation layer someplace at runtime.

There are significant sections of work in many applications that can be encapsulated as strongly-typed functions.  FFTs, convolutions, matrix operations and other types of array processing are good examples where a tightly-coded compiled loop can outperform a pure Python solution more than enough to pay for the runtime data copying and "environment switching" overhead.

There is also the case for "C as a portable assembler" to gain access to hardware functions for accelerating these functions.  The Python library may have a high-level interface that depends on driver code that's not available widely enough to be part of the Python execution model. Multimedia hardware for video and audio processing, and array processing instructions on the CPU or GPU are examples.

The costs for a custom hybrid solution are in development and maintenance.  There is added complexity in design, coding, building, debugging and deployment of the application.  You also need expertise on-staff for two different programming languages.